# How can I refresh swatches internally in Illustrator through jsx?

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I have a problem with Illustrator. When I loop through all the swatches like for all spot colors, it does not provide me all the swatches present in `swatches list`. But when I reopen the same document then it works fine . It's an illustrator bug so I'm thinking that there should be a way to refresh all the swatches internally. Please help trapped in such situation.